# Wildfly 23 server - Simple JAX-WS deployment - all attempts to access the WSDL are "Forbidden" OR "Not Found"

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jax-ws

While I am not new to JAX-WS, (used it years ago w/ Sun Metro JAX-WS RI w/o issues)... much has changed and I have been involved in MANY other web services projects involving REST endpoints, mainly w/ Spring Boot the past few years.

I am now involved in another project where the server stack is Wildfly 23 and they are using SOAP web services. I have a written a simple WAR project w/ an annotated Java class implementing an annotated Java interface. (the term is SEI in the documentation, it's been a few years). I just want to understand how JAX-WS services deploy and how the WSDL is accessed.

Service implementation class

```
package com.example.jaxws.ws;

import jakarta.jws.WebMethod;
import jakarta.jws.WebService;
import jakarta.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import jakarta.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService(
    serviceName = "EmployeeService",
    endpointInterface = "com.example.jaxws.ws.EmployeeService"
)
@SOAPBinding(
    style = Style.DOCUMENT
)
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {
    public EmployeeServiceImpl() {
    }

    @WebMethod
    public Employee getEmployee(int id) {
        return null;
    }

    @WebMethod
    public Employee addEmployee(int id, String name) {
        return new Employee(id, name);
    }
}
```

Service interface:

```
package com.example.jaxws.ws;

import jakarta.jws.WebMethod;
import jakarta.jws.WebService;
import jakarta.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style= SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
public interface EmployeeService {

    @WebMethod
    Employee getEmployee(int id);
    @WebMethod
    Employee addEmployee(int id, String name);
}
```

[image: The project structure]

The web.xml file looks like this (effectively an empty default)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">

    
</web-app>
```

Another post said one needs a jboss-web.xml, (same location /WEB-INF) so this was added

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web version="10.0"
           xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_10_0.xsd">

    <context-root>/employee-service</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Finally, the pom.xml contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JAXWS_Services</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JAXWS_Services</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The WAR project is added an Artifact to the Server instance within IntelliJ where a Wildfly run configuration was created. Starting the server shows ZERO errors, a context-root path created matching the jboss-web.xml. Yet navigating to anywhere on that context-root path results in a "Forbidden" error page AND a path to the WSDL (that I think should work based on other code I've seen), yields a 404 )

Clearly, I am missing a BIG something.  Any insight would be appreciated.

**Console output from startup:**

```
Connected to server
[2023-10-31 11:00:37,551] Artifact JAXWS_Services:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
23:00:37,763 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "JAXWS_Services-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "JAXWS_Services-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
23:00:39,883 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Corona Extra' 11.0.9.Final
23:00:39,965 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (MSC service thread 1-6) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
23:00:39,968 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (MSC service thread 1-6) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
23:00:40,115 INFO  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi.marshalling.InfinispanProtoStreamMarshaller'
23:00:40,452 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) WFLYCLINF0002: Started http-remoting-connector cache from ejb container
23:00:40,767 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/employee-service' for server 'default-server'
23:00:40,852 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "JAXWS_Services-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "JAXWS_Services-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
[2023-10-31 11:00:40,872] Artifact JAXWS_Services:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2023-10-31 11:00:40,872] Artifact JAXWS_Services:war: Deploy took 3,321 milliseconds
```

While the logging shows successful deployment and the establishment of the context-root path... I am not seeing evidence that the coded "web service" is actually running in the container.

Comment: Are you using WildFly 23 Preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to upgrade WildFly. WildFly 23 is a Jakarta EE 8 container. You potentially could use WildFly 23 Preview, however I would not suggest that. You should upgrade to the latest WildFly, at the moment it's 30.0.0.Final, which is a Jakarta EE 10 container.

Jakarta EE 8 still uses the `javax` namespace where as Jakarta EE 9+ uses the `jakarta` namespace. Your dependencies are Jakarta EE 9 depencies and your code uses the `jakarta` namespace, therefore requiring a Jakarta EE 9+ container. My personal opinion would be to skip Jakarta EE 9.1 and go straight to Jakarta EE 10.

Comment: James - MANY thanks for pointing this out. You are absolutely spot on, It was indeed the Jakarta EE container that was causing the problem.  We bumped up to a Jakarta EE9 compliant version, deployed the WAR file again... and it all worked as expected... the deployment showed the service name coming up and we were able to open the WSDL at the expected path.... hopefully this saves some others' time. Specifically we were able to use WildFly 26.1.3 to confirm it was the Jakarta EE issue.   Will likely end up on WildFly 28 or higher when it's all done. Appreciate you taking time to respond.

Comment: I'd highly recommend using WildFly 30.0.0.Final as it is patched for CVE-2023-44487.