# Wildfly 27 Server - Simple JAX-WS deployment - Deployment/Startup works - SOAP call results in Fault "unmarshall error"

Tags: java, soap, jboss, wildfly, jax-ws

I recently posted a question which is now resolved by upgrading from WildFly 23 to 27, where the simple JAX-WS endpoint deploys, you see the startup in the logs and the WSDL URL responds w/ the WSDL expected.  [Original post w/ deployment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77400299/wildfly-23-server-simple-jax-ws-deployment-all-attempts-to-access-the-wsdl-a)

Now after getting past the deployment issue, I used POSTMAN to import the WSDL from the WildFly-hosted endpoint. It loaded ok and the 2 operations were shown correctly.

The SOAP message is sent from POSTMAN TO the server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <getEmployee xmlns="http://ws.jaxws.example.com/">
      <arg0>100</arg0>
    </getEmployee>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and I get back the following response w/ an Error:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://ws.jaxws.example.com/", local:"arg0"). Expected elements are &lt;{}arg0> </faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

WSDL: (from the deployed service)

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.jaxws.example.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="EmployeeService" targetNamespace="http://ws.jaxws.example.com/">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://ws.jaxws.example.com/" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://ws.jaxws.example.com/" version="1.0">
<xs:element name="Employee" type="tns:employee"/>
<xs:element name="addEmployee" type="tns:addEmployee"/>
<xs:element name="addEmployeeResponse" type="tns:addEmployeeResponse"/>
<xs:element name="getEmployee" type="tns:getEmployee"/>
<xs:element name="getEmployeeResponse" type="tns:getEmployeeResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="addEmployee">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg1" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="addEmployeeResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:employee"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="employee">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getEmployee">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element form="qualified" name="id" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getEmployeeResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:employee"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="addEmployee">
<wsdl:part element="tns:addEmployee" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getEmployeeResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getEmployeeResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="addEmployeeResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:addEmployeeResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getEmployee">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getEmployee" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="EmployeeService">
<wsdl:operation name="addEmployee">
<wsdl:input message="tns:addEmployee" name="addEmployee"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:addEmployeeResponse" name="addEmployeeResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getEmployee">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getEmployee" name="getEmployee"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getEmployeeResponse" name="getEmployeeResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="EmployeeServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:EmployeeService">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="addEmployee">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="addEmployee">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="addEmployeeResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getEmployee">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getEmployee">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getEmployeeResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="EmployeeService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:EmployeeServiceSoapBinding" name="EmployeeServiceImplPort">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/employee-service/EmployeeService"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The JAXB annotated class for the "Employee" looks like this:

```
package com.example.jaxws.ws;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Employee")
@XmlType()
public class Employee {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int id;

    private String name;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

}
```

The service implementation and interface look like this:

```
package com.example.jaxws.ws;

import jakarta.jws.WebMethod;
import jakarta.jws.WebParam;
import jakarta.jws.WebResult;
import jakarta.jws.WebService;
import jakarta.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;

import java.util.UUID;

@WebService(serviceName = "EmployeeService", endpointInterface = "com.example.jaxws.ws.EmployeeService")
@SOAPBinding(style= SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(EmployeeServiceImpl.class);

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "Employee")
    public Employee getEmployee(@WebParam(name = "id", targetNamespace = "http://ws.jaxws.example.com/") int id) {

        String txid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        ThreadContext.put("txid", txid);
        Employee employee = new Employee(id, "Smith");
        logger.info("Employee: [] returned", employee.toString());
        return null;

    }

    @WebMethod
    public Employee addEmployee(int id, String name) {
        return new Employee(id, name);
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
package com.example.jaxws.ws;

import jakarta.jws.WebMethod;
import jakarta.jws.WebParam;
import jakarta.jws.WebService;
import jakarta.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style= SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
public interface EmployeeService {

    @WebMethod
    public Employee getEmployee(@WebParam(name = "id", targetNamespace = "http://ws.jaxws.example.com/") int id);
    @WebMethod
    Employee addEmployee(int id, String name);
}
```

The WSDL was generated. I have run wsconsume to see what classes it would generate for a client side call (but I ended up using POSTMAN for now just to do a basic test call on the service end).

No errors were seen during the code generation and I got a folder full of code:

[image]

I’m trying to understand why a Fault is returned.